# Login después de registro según tipo de usuario en laravel

Tags: laravel, login, registro

Estoy con un sistema sencillo que tiene dos tipos de usuarios. Unos administradores y otros clientes. Lo que quiero lograr es que después de que los clientes se registren, en el login automático, vayan a una url específica, diferente a la de los administradores.

Aclaro q estoy usando Laravel 8.

El login lo tengo resuelto así en el **LoginController**:

```
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if ( auth() -> user() -> type == 1 ) :

            return '/administracion';

        else :

            return '/panel';

        endif;

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/';
    }
```

Pero no sé cómo implementarlo en el **RegisterController**

Aguardo su ayuda! :)

Comment: que mecanismo de registro estas usando? el que trae laravel o creaste uno desde cero?

Comment: @NicolasAldana estoy usando el de Laravel

Comment: Te esta mandando a la ruta home cierto?

Comment: Te esta mandando a la ruta home cierto?

Comment: Te esta mandando a la ruta home cierto?

Comment: Cada vez q un usuario se registra me manda siempre a `/administracion` que es la ruta que tengo predefinida en `public const HOME = '/administracion';` Sólo cuando se loguean va a `/panel` si es un cliente, y a `/administracion` si es un administrador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, agregando lo siguiente en RegisterController:

```
public function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $type = $user -> type;
        switch ($type) {
            case 1:
                return redirect() -> route('home');
                break;
            default:
                return redirect() -> route('panel');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

en tu register controller puedes sobrescibir el metodo del trait RegistersUsers, cuando se termine el registro este valida que el metodo exista de lo contrario ejecuta el redirect to del provider, pon la misma logica del login en el RegisterController asi

```
public function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $type= $user->type;
    switch ($type) {
        case 1:
            return '/administracion';
            break;
        default:
            return '/panel';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @NicolasAldana . Me sirvió de guía. Ahí publique la respuesta. Esta función me imprimía en pantalla el string según el caso, pero no hacía un redirect.

Comment: perfecto :), aunque en algunos casos es mejor que manejes una tabla de roles pero si la aplicación es muy pequeña tu solución funcionara bien

Answer (score 1):

te recomendaría utilizar middleware y agrupar las rutas tanto para los administradores como para los clientes de esta forma los usuarios serian redirigidos de a sus recursos pertinentes y tendrás un sistema mas modulado.

1. primero creas el middleware  `php artisan make:middleware "nombre del middleware"`.
2. se te creara el archivo con el nombre que le diste en la ruta app\http\middleware en
   donde crearas la funcion perteneciente al direccionamiento.
3. vas a la ruta app\http\kernel.php y dento del atriuto routeMiddleware registras tu middleware con un alias.

   protected $routeMiddleware = [

   ```
       'alias' => \App\Http\Middleware\nombredelMiddleware::class,
   ];
   ```
4. por ultimo vas a tus rutas y agrupas todas las rutas que seran accesadas segun lo establecido por tu middleware.

   Route::middleware(['alias'])->group(function () {

   rutas y recursos que seran filtrados

   });

con esto seria suficiente para que administres los recursos, si en algun punto no explique bien te dejo la documentacion.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware