# No logro que funcione el codicional if blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando mostrar secciones del sitio dependiendo del rol de usuario.

Actualmente quiero filtrar una seccion que solo lo puede visualiar el rol admin y supervisor.

Esta son las tablas relacionadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el modelo user.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\UserResetPassword; 

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password','role_id','password','empresa',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    // uno role puede tener varios usuarios (inversa)
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class,'role_id','id');
    }
}
```

Este es el modelo role.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model

{

    protected $table='roles';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public $timestamps=false;

    //campos que se pueden modificar
    protected $fillable=[
        'nombre'
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

Hasta ahora he intentado estas opciones:

1.

```
{{-- solo los supervisores y admin pueden ver la seccion de accesos --}}
                    @if  (auth()->user()->role->nombre=='Admin')
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-users">
                                </i>
                                <span>
                                    Acceso
                                </span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right">
                                </i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{url('seguridad/usuario')}}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o">
                                        </i>
                                        Usuarios
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

2. 

```
{{-- solo los supervisores y admin pueden ver la seccion de accesos --}}
                            @if  (auth()->user()->role==1 or auth()->user()->role==3)
                                <li class="treeview">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-users">
                                        </i>
                                        <span>
                                            Acceso
                                        </span>
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right">
                                        </i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{url('seguridad/usuario')}}">
                                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o">
                                                </i>
                                                Usuarios
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            @endif
```

3. 

```
{{-- solo los supervisores y admin pueden ver la seccion de accesos --}}
                        @if  (auth()->user()->role==1 || auth()->user()->role==3)
                            <li class="treeview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-users">
                                    </i>
                                    <span>
                                        Acceso
                                    </span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right">
                                    </i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{url('seguridad/usuario')}}">
                                            <i class="fa fa-circle-o">
                                            </i>
                                            Usuarios
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
```

No me genera error pero tampoco cumple lo que necesito

Comment: No es necesario usar las `{{}}` dentro del `if` porque se puede usar PHP normalmente. Intenta solo poner: `@if ( auth()->user()->role == 'Admin' )'`

Comment: @BetaM El error sale en el if

Comment: @JuanRivera Ya lo hice, y no me genera error. Pero tampoco me muestra la seccion cuando ingreso con el rol admin

Comment: @BetaM Eso estaba viendo en la tabla, probe con el numero de id del rol y con el nombre pero tampoco me funciona. Igual ahi deje la tabla para que la mires

Comment: @BetaM listo ya lo actualice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo mal la consulta, si vas a evaluar el valor de la llave foránea entonces debe ser de está forma

```
auth()->user()->role_id === 1
```

Es decir debes ocupar la columna que sirve como llave foránea

Ahora sí lo que buscas es aprovechar la relación definida entonces debe ser así

```
auth()->user()->role->nombre === 'algo'
```

Comment: Tenía unos paréntesis de más, lo checas

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema esta en esta linea

```
@if  (auth()->user()->role==1 or auth()->user()->role==3)
```

->role no es un attributo de la tabla users, role es una relacion de users hacia la tabla roles, por lo que ->role te va a entregar un "modelo" de la tabla roles, no puedes compararlo directamente contra uno con role==1.

Recomendacion una de dos

`@if (auth()->user()->role_id == 1 || ...`

o

`@if (auth()->user()->role->nombre === 'Admin' || ...`

La segunda situacion, que no tiene que ver con esto pero lo hago notar, es que en tu Modelo User, en el $fillable tiene un attributo `empresa` y en tu tabla esta como `empresas_id`, eventualmente esto tampoco va a funcionar.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password','role_id','password','empresa',
    ];
```

Ahora para que cuides mejor tus practicas te recomendaria crear una clase tipo "helper" class RolesHelper por ejemplo en donde definas los tipos de roles y sus accesos y mandas llamar esas metodos en vez de tener este tipo de definiciones por TODO tu codigo.
Si algun dia quieres modificar y actualizar "algun rol" vas a tener que andar buscando por TODO tu codigo, en cambio asi solo vas y actualizas tu class RolesHelper y punto.

Answer (score 0):

la forma mas eficaz de administrar las secciones seria utilizar middleware debido a que es un filtrado desde el http,si llegaras a implementar lo que estas haciendo introduciendo la ruta especifica del recurso cualquier usuario independientemente de su rol podría entrar.

en caso de que quieras imprentar el middleware acá te dejo la documentación.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware

Pero una solución rápida para tu proyecto sería crear un condicional al inicio de tu vista, lo cual no es recomendable por optimización y buenas practicas, pero te puede funcionar.

```
<?php 
 if  (auth()->user()->role!=1 || auth()->user()->role!=3){
  header("Location: http://localhots:8000/error");
   die();
 }
 ?>
```

Lo más recomendable es el Filtrado desde las rutas con middleware

[Te dejo este link en donde se encuentra la solución detallada del middleware](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420253/login-despu%C3%A9s-de-registro-seg%C3%BAn-tipo-de-usuario-en-laravel/420809#420809)

Comment: Por qué usar `header` si estamos en Laravel?, sería más provechoso valernos de las herramientas que provee el framework como redirect y route

Comment: Además si estamos en Blade es totalmente innecesario aperturar y cerrar etiquetas PHP así como tampoco se debería usar die. Por otro lado no es esto muy parecido a lo que el OP ya intento?